# Press Enter to Continue Skipping subsequent

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm trying to make a program wait for the user to press a key before continuing multiple times. Preferrably, this would be any key, but I'm not too fussed if the user can only press <kbd>Return</kbd>/<kbd>Enter</kbd> to continue.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        System.out.print("1");
        System.in.read();
        System.out.print("2");
        System.in.read();
        System.out.print("3");
    }
}
```

The desired output is as such:

```
1
```

After the first press:

```
1
2
```

After the second press:

```
1
2
3
```

In reality what happens is this:

```
1
```

After the first press:

```
1
23
```

As you can see, it skips all subsequent indications to wait for a user input.

I've also tried using a scanner, and that works, but it allows the user to enter the text as well, which is something I'd prefer not to happen.

Comment: Just tried your code, and everything works find here.

Comment: @atomman: Not if you enter some characters before you hit `Enter`.

Comment: @Keppil: For me it does it regardless of whether text is entered or not. Maybe that's just Eclipse.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [`skip()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#skip%28long%29) and [`available()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#available%28%29) methods to discard the data before the next `read()`:

```
System.out.print("1");
System.in.read();
System.in.skip(System.in.available());
System.out.print("2");
System.in.read();
System.out.print("3");
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks. Now, is there any way of getting the same result without it being possible to enter text?

Comment: In a console window there is no way of reading the keyboard directly that I know. In Swing, you can create a `KeyListener` to only react to certain keys.

Comment: That's a shame, but oh well. Thank you for your help.